# Upper Nilradical of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra

If we define the upper nilradical of a ring as the sum of all nil ideals of the ring, how could we deduce from just this definition that this is a nil ideal? Thanks!

Comment: Are your nil ideals two sided?

Comment: @s.harp For future reference, there is no (significant volume of) ring theory literature that I'm aware of that ever refers to right or left ideals as simply "ideals". Two sidedness is always implied without the right-left adjectives. Might be good to beat this in mind unless there's some reason to expect otherwise

Comment: @rschwieb thanks for the comment, I'll beat it into my mind ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your nil ideals are two-sided proceed like this:

Let $I,J$ be two-sided nil ideals of a Ring $R$. We want to show that $I+J$ is also nil. To do this consider $R/J$ and $(I+J)/J$.

You can see rather easily that $(I+J)/J$ is a two-sided nil ideal of $R/J$: Let $[x] \in (I+J)/J$, then there exists a representative $a$ of $[x]$ that lies in $I$. Since then $a^n=0$ for some $n$, you get $[x]^n=[a]^n=[a^n]=0$ and $[x]$ is nilpotent. That $(I+J)/J$ is a two-sided ideal is a standard proof.

Let $x \in (I+J)$, since $(I+J)/J$ is nil, you have that $[x^n]=[x]^n=0$ for some $n$, but this implies $x^n \in J$. Since $J$ is nil you then have $(x^n)^m=0$ for some $m$, but this is the same as $x^{n+m}=0$ and $x$ is nilpotent.

So the sum of two (two-sided) nil ideals is again a (two-sided) nil ideal. Since elements of $\oplus_{\alpha \in A} I_\alpha$ are finite sums of the elements of $I_\alpha$ this statement shows inductively that the elements of any sum of two-sided nil ideals are nilpotent. So any sum of two-sided nil ideals is again a two-sided nil ideal.

If the nil ideals are not necessarily two-sided, then it is an open problem whether or not the sum of two ideals is again nil, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Köthe_conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture)

The proof I have written down is basically Lemma 1 that can be found [here](http://planetmath.org/propertiesofnilandnilpotentideals) but with more details.